# Best place to store files for download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a script that runs once a week and creates a CSV file. A download link is emailed out so users can download the file. I am currently storing the file in `/tmp/`. This works sometimes, but some users get an error and the logs show

```
ActionController::MissingFile occurred in csv_downloads#download:
Cannot read file tmp/filename.csv
```

What is a better way to store these files? Here is part of the current script

```
  csv_string = CSV.generate(write_headers: true, headers: HEADER) { |csv| write_data(csv) }
  file = File.new(File.join(Dir.pwd, "/tmp/#{@file_name}.csv"), "w+")
  file.write(csv_string)
  file.close
  file
```

Comment: One issue is that it looks like you are saving to `/tmp` and then trying to access `tmp` (without the /) which will be `<path to your rails app>/tmp`

Comment: @MaxWilliams I thought that might be it initially, but it works for some users, and it works in testing. I think its an issue with tmp/ getting cleared out before users can access the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the files are public why not to store them at `"#{Rails.root}/public/csv-files/#{@file_name}.csv"`. If `public` is not an option, then place them at some safe place. Not in `/tmp`, where they can be deleted by system.

`/tmp` dir is cleaned regularly by your system. Read this discussion for more info https://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up

Comment: my controller limits which users can access the file. Would it be best to just create a /downloads directory and put the files in there? I also asked the question to get a better understanding of how tmp/ works. What is clearing out this folder? When does it get cleared? When I put something there, how long can I expect it to stay there?